# In what order should I replace flooring and remodel closets?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, closet

On my list of home improvements I want to get done soon, I'm replacing my carpets with hardwood floors and also remodeling my closets. Does the order in which I do these home improvements matter? Will I regret doing the closets first if I have to change the floors later?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on a couple of things, the first being whether it is real wood or laminate. The second is whether the closets are in the same room as your plan on doing the new flooring. If the closets are to be in the same room I assume they will most likely have the same flooring. If this is true it would be easiest to get the floor in first and then proceed to do the closet(s).

Most of the time reach-in closets don't touch the floor but sometimes have about a half inch base that rests on the floor. Based on what you have told me the closets would have the same floor as every where else and shouldn't be a problem. Good luck!

Comment: The floors are engineered floors. We are planning on doing floors and closets throughout the apartment, so it would be the same room. The closets are reach-in closets. They would have doors.

Does it matter if  the closet touches the floor or not?